# How to load Observable rxjs/Rx lib faster in Angularjs2 (2.0.1)

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I'm a newbie in Angularjs2 
In angular1 i used promise to callback function, In angular2 I use

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
```

to load Observable lib, the problem is it load too much file 
[image]

and it make my web first-load too slow. 
Please help me to find the way make it more faster. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't import from the main `Rx` library, as that file `require`s all the other files. Just import what you need from individual files.

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';

Observable.of([1, 2, 3])
  .map(array => { return array.filter(num => num === 2) });
```

Here we are only importing the `Observable` a static `of` method, and the `map` operator.

Generally the operators will be imported from `rxjs/add/operator/{operator}` and the static methods on the `Observable` will be imported from `rxjs/add/oservable/{staticMethod}`